# How to make custom template include content from page editor without post loop?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a custom page template which only have header and an full-screen image. Following [codex article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) I created a custom page as following

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: My custom template
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php
// Start the loop.
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  // Include the page content template.
  get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

// End the loop.
endwhile;
?>
```

But when I create a new page using this template and add `<img src="link/to/image.jpg" alt="my image">` using page editor I get the image nested in many div's and an article tag (see below). What I want is just the image tag followed by `header` so that I can make it fullscreen not boxed. Is there any way to directly add (without post loop) content typed in the page editor to the page using custom templates?

I thought post loop adding all this extra stuff so I tried using just `get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );` without the loop but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

This line `get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );` fetch the content from `content-page.php`. If you dont want that and only display content then replace that line by following line.

`the_content();`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code for your template :

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: My custom template
*/

 get_header(); ?>

<?php

 get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

<img src="link/to/image.jpg" alt="my image">

?>
```

here display only one image which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just add featured image and get it by

> get_the_post_thumbnail();

or

> wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon );

and use it in your template.

Other thing remain same.

i think this is best solutation.